# Выделение подстроки в строке

Tags: javascript

```
let string=prompt(),stringsearch=prompt(),count=0,find,arr=[];
for(var i = 0;i<string.length;i++){
    find=string.indexOf(stringsearch, count)
    if(find==-1) {
        break;
    }
    else{
    arr.unshift(find);
    count=find+1;}}  
for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    document.querySelector('p').innerHTML=string;
    }   
    console.log(arr)
```

```html
<p id='p'></p>
```

В первом промпте я ввожу какой либо текст , во втором символ который нужно найти в этом тексте и подсветить. Найти вот он ищет , а подсветить не выходит. Выручайте

Comment: завязывайте называть переменные `b`, давайте переменным осмысленные названия, так как ети все `b,j,c,d,g` просто не возможно читать и понимать

Comment: поправил по возможности

Comment: просто реплейсом с регуляркой замену сделайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Если нужно выделить только первое совпадение**:

```js
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
var string,substring;

string = prompt();
substring = prompt();

paragraph.innerHTML = string.replace(substring, `<span>${substring}</span>`);
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```

**Если нужно выделить все совпадения**:

```js
var paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
var string,substring;

string = prompt();
substring = prompt();

var re = new RegExp(substring, 'g');
paragraph.innerHTML = string.replace(re, `<span>${substring}</span>`);
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```